# Problem passing data from one component to another in livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

Good day, I am passing information from one component to another from a SELECT, when I do not load the information from the json file it works, but when I extract from the json I have the following error.

```
ErrorException
```

Trying to get property 'numero_prestamo_original' of non-object (View: C:\laragon\www\prestamos-cth\resources\views\livewire\prestamos\prestamos.blade.php)

The select field:

```
<option value="2022006799">2022006799</option>
    @foreach ($prestamos as $prestamo => $valor)
        <option value="{{ $valor->numero_prestamo_original }}">{{ $valor->numero_prestamo_original }}
        </option>
    @endforeach
```

Do you have any idea what is happening. thank you very much.

I have seen on the internet to make the change from -> to [ ] but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Do some debugging to determine the type that your $valor property actually is. That should identify how you should be using it in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help, the solution I found for that problem was to do the search with the required fields in the array and only print what is needed. Thanks for your help.